# ios - How to open a document in an iOS app in a modal window (like Google Drive)?

Tags: ios, swift

This stackoverflow post describes how to open a document in an iOS app:
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) - but it always opens as a fullscreen app.

How can I open a modal window like Google Drive does?

[image]

Comment: Use `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me how I can use the UIActivitiyViewController to *consume* a document (like GDrive on the right side of my screen). Can you add some more information?

Comment: The screens you posted in your question begin with a `UIActivityViewController`. Your question is very unclear so that's the best answer you are going to get without further clarification.